# Host Angular Universal 9 on Azure App Service with .Net stack

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, universal

I have Angular Universal 9 & standard Angular 9. I have to host on Azure app service with stack: .Net 4.7. Angular Universal local as expected but when I deploy it on Azure web service is not working. Currently, an app with Angular 9 is working but I have a problem with deploying an app with Angular Universal 9. Normal angular 9 application is working as expected on the same Azure app service. Do I need to configure Node.js separately on it?

Comment: According to your description, I tried it myself. Both Angular Universal 9 and standard Angular 9 are running normally after deployment. It may be that you have a little problem when deploying. The demo code block and running screenshot I will show in the answer, I hope to help you.

Comment: I don't know if my answer is helpful to you, I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this question?. I have facing same problem. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In App Services, under the `site\wwwroot` folder, the content stored should contain deployable files similar to index.html.

In the standard angular project, it should be the content under the `dist\my-angular-app` folder. In the Angular Universal 9 project, it should be the contents of the dist `dist\ng-universalv9\browser` folder.

The picture below is the directory structure of my Angular Universal 9 project and a comparison with the standard angular dist folder.

[image]

[image]

The stack selected by both projects is .net 4.7, and they work fine. I use FTP to deploy the project, the content under the specific wwwroot folder can be viewed and managed with `kudu`. You can view the contents of the `wwwroot` folder of your universal ng project. The following is a screenshot of my universal app, I hope to help you.

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details about your configuration? Do you have a web.config file?

Comment: Can you share more details.

Comment: I just follow the offical document step，create demo sample.

Comment: can you share your web.confg file

Comment: Doesn't Angular Universal use the server/main.js to serve the files though, which needs Node to operate? How do you do this in your web.config?